# como paro mi funcion de javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una funcion de javascript que se realiza cuando se cumple una condicion, mi intencion es que esta funcion se pare si la condicion no se cumple. Me gustaria que la función se deteniese en cuando no se cumpla el if.
Aqui está lo que he intentado junto a la función meteor que produce un efecto de lluvia dentro de la página:

```
 document.getElementById("lluvia").addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (document.getElementById("lluvia").checked == true) {
            meteor();
        }else{
            break meteor()
        }
    }
    );


function meteor() {
        let amount = 250;
        let body = document.querySelector("body");
        let count = 0;

        while (count < amount) {
            let drop = document.createElement("i");

            let size = Math.random() * 5;
            let posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
            let delay = Math.random() * -20;
            let duration = Math.random() * 2;

            drop.style.width = `${0.1 + size}px`;
            drop.style.left = `${posX}px`;
            drop.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;
            drop.style.animationDuration = `${0 + duration}s`;

            body.appendChild(drop);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Hugo, debes ser mas especifico con lo que quieres realizar... además también de subir código para que podamos saber cual es el problema y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya he reformulado la pregunta David. Queda mas claro así?

Comment: que hace la función meteor? es esa la que deseas detener? agrega el codigo de esta

Comment: Ya he subido todo el codigo de la funcion meteor. Si es esa la que quiero detener

Comment: @HugoOlivaRomero, seguramente estan faltando los estilos para los `i`, cierto? Con respecto a "detener", ¿será que queres que se eliminen todos los `i` creados o que la animación se detenga?

Comment: para detener una función prueba con return o return false..
Esto detiene la ejecución de una función o el flujo de un algoritmo

Comment: Me gustaria que se eliminasen todos los `i`

Comment: Si no tienes mas elementos de tipo `i` en el documento que interfieran con el código, entonces puedes hacer `[...document.querySelectorAll("i")].map(e => e.remove());`

Answer (score 0):

Haz lo siguiente:

```
var parar = false;
document.getElementById("lluvia").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("lluvia").checked == true) {
        parar = false;
        meteor();
    }else{
        parar = true;
    }
}
);


function meteor() {
    let amount = 250;
    let body = document.querySelector("body");
    let count = 0;

    while (count < amount) {
        if(parar == false){
           let drop = document.createElement("i");

           let size = Math.random() * 5;
           let posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
           let delay = Math.random() * -20;
           let duration = Math.random() * 2;

           drop.style.width = `${0.1 + size}px`;
           drop.style.left = `${posX}px`;
           drop.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;
           drop.style.animationDuration = `${0 + duration}s`;

           body.appendChild(drop);
           count++;
        }else{
           break;
        }   
    }
 }
```